# jpg not being overwritten by ImageIO.write()

Tags: java, jpeg, javax.imageio

I've made the following example, I can't figure out why it isn't working.

- None of my checks are returning false,
- I have read and write permissions,
- the imageIO responds that it has in fact overwritten the image,
- no exceptions are thrown...

but the image still hasn't changed on disk.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            try
                {
                    // load a jpg file
                    File imageFile = getFile();

                    // Make a Buffered Image from it
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageFile);

                    // for every pixel in the image
                    for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
                        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
                            // check if the RGB integer is an odd number
                            if (img.getRGB(x, y) % 2 != 0)
                                // make it an even number if it is odd (the OCD god demands it!)
                                img.setRGB(x, y, img.getRGB(x, y) - 1);

                    // Write the OCD friendly version to the file
                    System.out.println("Was overwritten: " + ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", imageFile));
                    System.out.println();

                    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                    // Select the same file again
                    imageFile = getFile();

                    // Make the bufferedImage from it
                    img = ImageIO.read(imageFile);

                    // for every pixel in the image
                    for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
                        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
                            // check if the RGB integer is an odd number
                            if (img.getRGB(x, y) % 2 != 0)
                                {
                                    // Report the failing
                                    System.out.println("It didn't work :(");
                                    // Stop the loop
                                    x = img.getWidth();
                                    y = img.getHeight();
                                }
                }
            catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    public static File getFile()
        {
            // set up a file chooser that only accepts jpgs
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG Images only", "jpg"));

            // This will represent our loaded file
            File imageFile = null;

            // Select a file
            chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            imageFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

            // Check we can do stuff to this file
            System.out.println("Exists: " + imageFile.exists());
            System.out.println("Can Read: " + imageFile.canRead());
            System.out.println("Can Write: " + imageFile.canWrite());
            System.out.println();

            return imageFile;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is overwritten, you just don't detect that visually with your 
eyes. That is because you change the RGB values by just 1.

```
for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
        // check if the RGB integer is an odd number
        if (img.getRGB(x, y) % 2 != 0)
            // make it an even number if it is odd (the OCD god demands it!)
            img.setRGB(x, y, 0); /// A ///
```

Change this line `/// A ///` as I did and you'll see it is overwritten.

Of course it also depends on the picture you're testing this on.
If `img.getRGB(x, y)` is never odd, the `img.setRGB` will never be executed.

Comment: So I set that line to /// img.setRGB(x, y, 0); /// and while it did modify the image, it did weird things instead of setting it to a plain colour, the basic image kinda shows but is mostly lost in static, what the hell is happening?! It is like it is trying to superimpose the original image onto some sort of white and black static background... is this something to do with the jpg compression?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do exactly but your image is overwritten. This was your question.

Comment: The example above was really dumbed down code, I'm playing around with hiding data in images, with odd numbered pixels representing a '1' and even pixels representing a '0', so ideally I'd like pixels that I change the value of by one to stay changed. My problem is that if you run the original program, and make all the pixels even, and then recheck that image, it still has odd pixels...

Comment: To answer your previous question, I think it is due to the `if (img.getRGB(x, y) % 2 != 0)`. Remove it and it will become all black.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm an idiot... any ideas as to why pixel values aren't staying odd or even?

Comment: ImageIO JPG standard compression. You can change color values but the ImageIO default compression will most likely change it.

Comment: Yes, I printed out the new values (which you're setting), they are all even so then apparently ImageIO.write is kind of replacing them as Vynz noted. That's why on the next read, you see odd values again.

Comment: Try it, I am not a picture expert :) Look at your original question :)

Comment: Ok, so you answered my original question =P you'll get an accepted answer! I literally just changed the ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", imageFile) to ImageIO.write(img, "png", imageFile) and voila! (I was under the impression that it had to match the file extension or it wouldn't work for some reason...)

Comment: Well, such assumptions are often misleading. I believe only the JavaDoc and the tests I am doing. Good that you solved your problem. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29